# Problem when trying to upload zip/rar files with the milesjohnson's upload plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I'm new to cakephp and I have found this [milesjohnson's upload plugin](http://milesj.me/code/cakephp/uploader#script) ,
and I kind of like it, mostly because it gives me the chance of renaming the file once uploaded.Unfortunately, I can't get it to upload any zip/rar files.

This is the action where I upload the file:

```
function add() {
        if (!empty($this->data)) {

            if ($data = $this->Uploader->upload('link_referencia', array('name' => date("dmYhis")))) {
                 debug($data);
                 $this->data['Publicacione']['link_referencia']=$data['name'];
            }
            $this->Publicacione->create();

            if ($this->Publicacione->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The publicacione has been saved', true));
                //$this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The publicacione could not be saved. Please, try again.', true));
            }
        }
        $users = $this->Publicacione->User->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('users'));
    }
```

And this is the error I get everytime I attempt to upload any zip/rar file :[image]

**EDIT**

Full insert query:

```
INSERT INTO `publicaciones` (`vigencia`, `tipo`, `titulo`, `descripcion`, `fecha_publicacion`, `fecha_caducidad`, `link_referencia`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES (1, 'c', 'there\'s nothing you can\'t do', '
fsdfsdfsdf
', '2011-06-07', '2011-06-30', Array, '2011-06-07 16:47:23', '2011-06-07 16:47:23')
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's exactly in `$data['name']`? A filename as a string, or an array? Can you save your data without doing the upload?

Comment: @vindia- $data is an array populated with the values for the uploaded files: filesize, name, extension, mime group, destination path, upload time and width/height (if an image) and yes I can save the data without doing the upload

Comment: Could you please paste the full insert query from your error screenshot?

Comment: @vindia- I added the full insert query, please take a look at it.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that `$data['name']` is not a string, but an array and is therefore added as `Array` to your `INSERT` query, which triggers the error.

Comment: looks like u have not used the attachment behavior which will automatically attach the file to the particular field.

Answer (score 0):

i think there is nothing with the code what you have written but you should look at in to the plugin and find out whether it gives permission you to upload zip or not.

there will be conditions in your pluggin that you can upload only some kind of files like jpg,png,txt something like that.

I hope that helps you.

Regards,
Archit

Answer (score 0):

Are you totally sure your File input on the form has type=>file specified, and same for your form?

Also I would look at other uploaders - MeioUpload can allow renaming and so on and is a bit more up to date. There is also the Cuploadify plugin (uploadify for cake) you can find on github.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your form is set to

```
multipart/form-data
```

like so:

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('File', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data')); ?>
```

The following code will upload a file:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {


    if ( $this->data['File']['file']['error'] <= 0  && $this->data['File']['file']['size'] <=   8388608 ) { // Check for no errors and that File size is around 8mb.

    $folder = new Folder (ROOT . DS . 'app' . DS . 'filestorage' . DS, true);  // create folder in /app/filestorage/

    $path = $folder->path . $this->data['File']['file']['name']; // Set path to newly created folder + uploaded file name.

    $tmpUrl = new File ( $this->data['File']['file']['tmp_name'] ); // Create temporary file object

    if ($tmpUrl->copy($path , true) ) { // If copying file to path is successful,

        $this->Session->setFlash(__('File uploaded succesfully!'));   

     }
}
```